# Method testLeapYear does not exist in the the apex class with Id

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex

I am trying to run the tests from below Test class and getting error as "Method testLeapYear does not exist in the the apex class with Id :01p5g00000iZVmG" .

```
@IsTest
public with sharing class SingletonTest {
    @IsTest
    public static void testLeapYear() {
        //not stubbed out, so this will take the normal path w/o the switch
        SingletonController.printDateTime();
    }

    @IsTest
    public static void testNonLeapYear() {
        //IS stubbed out, so this WILL take the alternate path
        DateTime newNow = DateTime.newInstance(2019, 9, 8);
        DateTimeProvider.instance = new DateTimeStub(newNow);
        SingletonController.printDateTime();
        //in the wild, return data and make assertions here
    }
    
    private with sharing class DateTimeStub extends DateTimeProvider {
        public DateTime now;
        
        public DateTimeStub(DateTime now) {
            this.now = now;
        }
        
        public override DateTime now() {
            return now;
        }
    }
}
```

The other classes are as follows:

- **DateTimeProvider.cls:**

```
    public virtual with sharing class DateTimeProvider {
        @TestVisible
        private static DateTimeProvider instance;
    
        public static DateTimeProvider getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new DateTimeProvider();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    
        protected DateTimeProvider() {
        // protected constructor for testability - use getInstance() instead
        
        }
    
        public virtual DateTime now() {
            return DateTime.now();
        }
    }
```

- **SingletonController.cls** as follows:

```
public with sharing class SingletonController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void printDateTime() {
        DateTimeProvider dateProvider = DateTimeProvider.getInstance();
        System.debug('Hey, is it a leap year?');

        Boolean isLeapYear = Date.isLeapYear(dateProvider.now().year());

        if (isLeapYear) {
            System.debug('Yep! Get testing!');
        } else {
            System.debug('All clear. Enjoy your free time :) ');
        }
    }
}
```

This is referenced from this Salesforce blog: https://engineering.salesforce.com/simplify-testing-with-the-singleton-pattern-1a53ba5c2c50/

Can you please let me know if I am missing something?

I have tried :

1. Adding test.start
2. Deploying Source to org
3. Running the same set of code on the Developer console

Comment: Is the test class saved ok to the org? Can you see the "missing" method ok in the org (setup-> apex classes or developer console)? Stupid but are you sure you're in the right org?

Comment: Yes @eyescream , I was able to fix it. As the code was not correctly deployed to the org, so I fixed the issue by creating the classes and running them directly from Developer console on the salesforce org. Thanks.